# How to extract non-existing props as null or empty String from a JSON array by using JSON path

Tags: arrays, jsonpath

I have Json like this below

```
{
    'orderList': [
        {
            'productId': 'AAA',
        },
        {
            'productId': 'BBB',
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSON String is valid when all items in `orderList` have non-empty `productId` prop,  I'm tring to using JsonPath to validate, now I have a problem. `$.orderList[*]['productId']` can extract all productIds from `orderList` as a String array like `['AAA', 'BBB']`, that allows me to check it's items are all non-empty, but when `productId` prop is not exists like below

```
{
    'orderList': [
        {
            'productId': 'AAA',
        },
        {
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSON path

```
$.orderList[*]['productId']
```

gets an array as `['AAA']` ( not `['AAA', null]` or `['AAA', '']` ), so it can pass my check functions. How to do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how jsonpath works. If it did not find that property in the object it ignores that in the result array instead of adding a `null` or `undefined` values. So, if you want to get the `null` in the result array then you need to add that property with `null` as value.

```
{
    "orderList": [
        {
            "productId": "AAA"
        },
        {
            "productId": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Will result to

```
[
  "AAA",
  null
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this means I need to use Json Schema to validate JSON string instead of JSON path。

Comment: @user1021531 you can follow that too